How is the \$M^2\$ term derived in the PLL output phase noise spectrum?
Originally, I was interested in the derivation of Equation 12.5 in the RF synthesis chapter of Razavi's textbook Design of phase-locked loops.

I tried to look up the origin of it and found out a very similar equation in page 265
.
And then I tried to understand its derivation and found out an explanation of \$M^2\$ term in Example 8.9

However, I don't understand his explanation that

For an input of the form \$V_1cos[\omega_{in}(t)+\phi_{n,in}(t)]\$, the output emerges as \$V_2cos[M\omega_{in}t+M\phi_{n,in}(t)]\$,where the \$\phi_{n,in}\$ represents the in-band phase noise. Thus, the output spectrum is \$M^2\$ times that at the input.

Why

Thus, the output spectrum is \$M^2\$ times that at the input?

What am I missing in here?
Another question I don't understand is: Why does equation 12.5 include an additional term of dividing by \$2\pi\$ compared to equation 8.42?
Thanks for your time!\
M is the fraction ration of the fractional-N PLL as image below illustrating


It might be useful to tell us what M is, how measured, and whether the noise and jitter are measured as power, or voltage or seconds or root(power). That's the usual cause for unexpected squarings or rootings when going through that sort of calculation.

@Neil_UK, I really appreciate of your reply! M is the fraction ration of fractional-N PLL, I will upload an image right after the question to illustrate it.

The PLL simply "amplifies" the phase quantities by \$ M \$ within its bandwidth. Thus, a factor of \$ M \$ emerges in the input-output relation. When dealing with power spectral densities of stochastic processes, \$ \vert H(s) \vert ^2 \$ is of interest, hence the factor \$ M^2 \$.
As for the second question, equations 8.42 and 12.5 are related by the  \$ \omega_{-3dB} = 2\pi f_{-3dB} \$ equality.

Sir, I sincerely appreciate your comprehensive explanation! I just have one last question: How is Equation 8.40 derived, that is the relationship between PSD and Phase Noise?  I tried to look it up on Razavi's another textbook RF microelectronics Sec 8.7 Phase noise but didn't find anything useful.

@TongSu Input to the PLL has a phase noise spectrum, $ S_0 $, which upon experiencing the PLL transfer function (and assuming a single pole response for large $ \zeta $) yields the integrand in equation 8.40. By integrating this value (which is the PSD of the output phase noise only because of the input and disregarding the VCO) you can get the full integrated phase noise at the output. The key points here are the one-pole approximation to the PLL response for a large damping factor and the magnitude squared of the transfer function acting on the input PSD.
